# MS excel time in range

Tags: excel, datetime

I have time in this  - > `05/21/16 15:44`

I'm not bothered about the date part, I want to see if the time falls between 10 AM to 8 PM or not. For this record it is 3 PM so its good.

I have tried extracting time out, tryin Median, Mod functions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `=AND(MOD(A1,1)>=TIME(10,0,0),MOD(A1,1)<=TIME(20,0,0))` works for me.

Comment: works @ – Scott Crane

Comment: or in short: `=MOD(A1-5/12,1)<=5/6`

Comment: @DirkReichel this returns TRUE for `5/21/2016  5:00:00 AM` which it should not.  because 5AM - 10 hours is 7 PM which satisfies the condition

Comment: @DirkReichel I think you want the `5/6` to be `5/12`

Comment: @ScottCraner good catch... the error is at `5/6`... simply forgot to apply the offset to the end time... `=MOD(A1-5/12,1)<=5/12` is correct

Comment: @DirkReichel otherwise great 3 dimensional thinking.  It makes perfect sense as I dissected the formula.  Very concise.  will you put that as an answer, so we can link to it for duplicates?

Comment: @ScottCraner that is more the math way of solving it... while it would fit as an answer... there are just to many solutions like `=MOD(A1,1)=MEDIAN(MOD(A1,1),5/12,5/6)` or whatever... also it is not that much obvious if you need to change the formula later on... I would stick with your formula (unless it is calculated so many times, that speed matters)

Answer (score 0):

Two offers from Comments:

[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358244/ms-excel-time-in-range#comment64128780_38358244):

```
=AND(MOD(A1,1)>=TIME(10,0,0),MOD(A1,1)<=TIME(20,0,0))
```

[Dirk Reichel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358244/ms-excel-time-in-range#comment64129466_38358244):

```
=MOD(A1-5/12,1)<=5/12
```

They differ according to treatment of time at the cusp.